# Netbeans unusable after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: netbeans, osx-yosemite

Just updated to Yosemite and now when i open Netbeans it gets freeze in 42% on 'Background scanning of projects' and eating 200% CPU. So i have to manually close it.

Any information about this problem ? My IDE is updated (8.0.1) and my machine is a Macbook 15", Core i7, 16GB ram.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have this issue on osx Yosemite, after netbeans 8.0.1 starts and one minute passes , I get the beach ball cursor and it stays like this for at least 20 min

Any one encountered this issue or has a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After waiting about 10 minutes the background scanning ended to 100% and now Netbeans is usable again.

Comment: You marked the wrong answer as correct. @Kinman should get the credit.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I had to do an SMC reboot of my laptop and it fixed it.

For the newer unibody (non-removable battery) MacBooks it is done by

1. Power down the laptop.
2. Hold Left Shift, Left Control, Left Option and the Power button together, and then let go.
3. Power on the laptop.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: After waiting about 10 minutes the background scanning ended to 100% and now Netbeans is working. Anyways, thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score -1):

Just install the latest JRE for Apple found here  : http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US and it should work just fine!